# "django.db.utils.DatabaseError: Cannot add foreign key constraint" while using multiple ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models

I'm getting below error while migrating my model.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\django\base.py", line 115,
 in _execute_wrapper
    return method(query, args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 507, in e
xecute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 722,
in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 640,
in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key const
raint


in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 640,
in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Please help me to solve this error. Thanks in advance !!!

Below are my models :

category model :

```
class categories(models.Model) :
    id = dbUtils.BigAutoField(primary_key = True)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True)
```

feeds model :

```
class feeds(models.Model) :
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank = True )
    country = models.ManyToManyField(countries,related_name='feedcountry')
    state = models.ManyToManyField(states,related_name='feedstate')
    city = models.ManyToManyField(cities,related_name='feedcity')
```

feedsMapping model :

```
class feedsMapping(models.Model) :
    id = dbUtils.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    feeds = dbUtils.BigForeignKey(feeds, related_name='feedmap')
    language = dbUtils.BigForeignKey(languages, related_name='feedmaplanguage')
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(categories,verbose_name='feedmapcategories')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.ManyToManyField(countries,related_name='feedmapcountry')
    state = models.ManyToManyField(states,related_name='feedmapstate')
    city = models.ManyToManyField(cities,related_name='feedmapcity')
```

Comment: Could you post your models? Any previous migrations?

Comment: Added model with question. This error occurred in initial migration.

Comment: Can you please add your `Django` version and point us to where `dbUtils` comes from?